# Can't install 19.04

Tags: 19.04

I'm having a lot of problems installing ubuntu, I tried with a USB, didn't work, i tried unetbootin, didnt work, i disabled secure boot and fast boot in bios, still didn't work,

I'm so close to giving up right now.

EDIT: USB just gave me a error saying "can't boot from usb" or something, and unetbootin gave me some different error but i dont remember what it said.

CPU: i7-8750H
GPU: RTX 2080 Max-Q
RAM: 16GB DDR4
OS(im using right now): Windows 10

EDIT: Etcher worked, However, ubuntu doesnt detect my SSD, only the USB.

Comment: What exactly did not work? What are the hardware specs?

Comment: I would suggest using the 'check disc for defects' option on the install media (to ensure your download & write to media were flawless), however yes some BIOS/UEFI setsups are a pain requiring the correct combination otherwise the UEFI boot data cannot be written to it (your installed OS doesn't get errors; the UEFI just prevents writes but responds as if data is written) so check your setup for your ?? box.

Comment: Please provide the model number as obtained from the serial number sticker (we don't want your serial number, just the model number) and add that to your original question by clicking [edit]. Please do not use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying to use another USB 'Burning' application. I tend to use 'Etcher' these days after Unetbootin started be unreliable for me.

https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Comment: This worked, however, when installing, it doesn't show my SSD, only the USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

Etcher - Appimage Ubuntu 19.04-10 every Ubuntu iso I installed has worked perfectly + formatted the usb drive with Gparted. Maybe you can try a different USB stick.